# Mac Sandbox and XCode 3.x

Tags: xcode, macos, sandbox, appstore-sandbox

Is there a way to be Sandbox-compliant compiling apps with XCode 3.x?

Are there any articles or tutorials out there on how to do this?

I'm the developer of a Mac application and I'm stuck with XCode 3 because
the app uses two `IBPlugins` which (as far as I know) are not supported in
XCode 4.x. Sandboxing apps will be mandatory to publish them on the Mac
AppStore beginning November 2011 (still no updates on this, any news?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create an entitlements property list by hand and sign your application bundle from the command line, as described in the [Code Signing And Application Sandboxing Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/CodeSigningGuide/ApplicationSandboxing/ApplicationSandboxing.html). You may need to have a copy of Xcode 4 installed for its version of the `codesign` utility, however you can have multiple versions installed simultaneously (refer to the [`xcrun`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/xcrun.1.html) and [`xcode-select`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/xcode-select.1.html) `man` pages).